MISP and running TAXII server
I have two MISP servers. First one has internet access and can connect to feeders like CIRCL. The second instance has no access to internet, but have access to first server. The third server has Suricata with no internet.
I need to run a TAXII server in first server and use it to feed threat intels to two other servers.
I ran TAXII server with this docker compose file.
version: '3'
services:
  medallion:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker_utils/Dockerfile
    command: [sh, -c, "medallion --host 0.0.0.0"]
    environment:
      MEDALLION_BACKEND_MODULE_CLASS: "MongoBackend"
      MEDALLION_BACKEND_MONGO_URI: "mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_HOST: mongo
      MONGO_PORT: 27017
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongo
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT: 27017
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN: "true"
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
    depends_on:
      - mongo

And this Dockerfile
FROM python:alpine

COPY . /opt/taxii
WORKDIR /opt/taxii
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools \
    && pip install pymongo \
    && pip install .

# Set up the default configuration files
ARG MEDALLION_CONFFILE=/opt/taxii/medallion.conf
ENV MEDALLION_CONFFILE "${MEDALLION_CONFFILE}"
COPY ./docker_utils/base_config.json "${MEDALLION_CONFFILE}"
ARG MEDALLION_CONFDIR=/opt/taxii/medallion.d/
ENV MEDALLION_CONFDIR "${MEDALLION_CONFDIR}"
COPY ./docker_utils/config.d/ "${MEDALLION_CONFDIR}/"

But when i ran MISP to push data to TAXII server, in jobs i have this error
Error: Command '/usr/local/bin/python3 /var/www/MISP/app/files/scripts/taxii/taxii_push.py --dir /var/www/MISP/app/tmp/Taxii/aIBcLgPekdkw --baseurl http://X.X.X.X:5000 --api_root 0 --key API-KEY --collection ' finished with error code 1.
STDERR: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/MISP/app/files/scripts/taxii/taxii_push.py", line 9, in <module>
import taxii2client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'taxii2client'

What else I should do?
As i said, I have a Suricata server. i cant use remote server instead of TAXII. I test remote server in MISP successfully. but for Suricata, I need TAXII server.
